# notifyItemChanged(position) is not updating the view

Tags: android, user-interface, android-arrayadapter, android-recyclerview

What I am doing:

RecyclerView -> calling new fragment onRecyclerView Item Click(through interface) -> updaing somthing in new fragment -> closed the current fragment-> trying to update the selected item data. (calling notifiyItemChanged(position))

But data is not updated on UI side, I checked ArrayList is updating (through debugger).

Reason: notifiyItemChanged(position) is not calling the onBindViewHolder()

Code:

RecyclerView Intilization:

```
mLayoutGridManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4);
     mTableAdapter = new TableAdapter(getActivity(),    RoomFragment.this);
    mTableRecyclerView.setAdapter(mTableAdapter);
    mTableRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mTableRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutGridManager);
```

Calling Fragment:

```
tableOrderDetails = TableOrderDetailsFragment.newInstance(table,position);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, tableOrderDetails);
        transaction.addToBackStack(CustomerListFragment.TAG);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

//updating the views

```
public void updateTable(int tableID, String tableStatus, int position){

             if (data.get(position).getTableID()==tableID && tableStatus!=null){
                data.get(position).setCurrentTableStatus(tableStatus);

                 notifyItemChanged(position);
             }
      }
```

#Possible Reason:
Views are not attached.

Solution Tried:

1. notifyDataSetChanged()
2. runOnUiThred
3. call update function using Looper.

Comment: where are you calling the recycleview initialization, fragment, updating the views? provide the lifecycle states. also, this is on a class extending Activity or Fragment?

Comment: @EvOlaNdLuPiZ basically i have initialized the recycled view in fragment and calling other fragment via activity

Comment: i'm referring to [android documentation for activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) and [android documentation for fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments).

Comment: when you say you initialize, what part of the lifecycle does this take place inside your code? onCreate() or onCreateView()?

Comment: @EvOlaNdLuPiZ oncreateView